# Auto adjust height of content

Tags: html, height

I'm having a very specific issue with my website that I can't seem to come up with an easier solution because the current solution that I'm using is tedious as heck. So I have three columns and each one has an image and a little description of that image underneath. The problem comes when I have to change the height of each individual column.

Currently, I have specified the height of each column and if I decide to add more text underneath the image, I have to manually change the height of the column which can be tedious. I just want to be able to have each column to auto adjust the height automatically and the bottom border should be a straight line. Look at the image to understand what I mean.

**Here's the image**

http://i44.tinypic.com/2qipv06.jpg

**HTML**

```
     <article class="in-column" style="height:362px;"> <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"> <img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" height="200" width="300"></a>
          <p class="excerpt">Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism

      </article>

               <article class="in-column" style="height:374px;"> <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"> <img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" width="300" height="200"></a>

               <p class="excerpt">Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism

          </article>        

   </section> 


    <section id="middle-container">           

           <article class="in-column" style="height:377px;"> <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" width="300" height="200"></a>

                <p class="excerpt">Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism

                </article>          

               <article class="in-column" style="height:359px;"> <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" width="300" height="200"></a>

                <p class="excerpt">Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism 

                 </article>          

   </section> 


  <section id="right-container" class="right-column" style="width:351px; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;">          

       <article class="in-column" style="height:343px;"><a href="http://yahoo.com"> <img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" width="300" height="200"></a>

               <p class="excerpt">Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism

             </article>          

                 <article class="in-column" style="height:393px;"> <a href="http://yahoo.com"> <img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" height="200" width="300"></a>

               <p class="excerpt">Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and  Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism 

        </article>                                     

      </section>
     </section>
```

**CSS**

```
      #content .subheading {
color: #657B83;
font-size: 22px;
height:40px;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgb(204, 204, 204);
padding-top:10px;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 0px;

 }

 #content { 
overflow: hidden;
width: 1055px;

 }

 .right-column {
width: 350px;    
float: left;
border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;

 }

 .left-column {
width: 350px;
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;

 }

 article.in-column {    
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;    
padding-top: 15px;  

 }

 article.in-column .excerpt {
color: #2f2f2f;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
padding-bottom: 5px;    
font-family:"Segoe UI";
 }

 #middle-container {        
width: 350px;
float: left;
position: relative; 

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a quick fix, try `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. But this has issues with IE 7. Check this Fiddle for a working demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/LzcJx/

Also have a look at this link to do it without any cross browser issues.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-3-column.htm

Comment: Your suggested solution was to fix columns issue, not rows. I've seen many discussions about columns height but that doesn't help fill my rows' height till the bottom of the screen. display:table and table-cell doesn't auto doesn't fill/adjust the height.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each `</article>` element with a div that is your set height and then make the `</article>` elements height 100%.

That way each `</article>` is the height you want it to be and everything in it will be 100%.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PgRw/11/) as example.